# Isolating PANDAS Dataframe entries within a column that contain brackets within a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a PANDAS dataframe, df. This dataframe has a column, SMILES, that contains strings that have the SMILES representation of chemicals.

In SMILES, each letter represents an atom. If I want to make a new dataframe, newdf, that isolates chemicals that have oxygen, I can use:
`newdf1=df[df['SMILES'].str.contains('O')].reset_index(drop=True)`
This successfully creates a new dataframe that only has chemicals that have oxygen.

In SMILES, to represent chemicals that contain atoms covalently bonded to 3 or more other non-hydrogen atoms, you have to use brackets "(" and ")". For example, for isobutane the SMILES representation is "CC(C)C". I want to extract chemicals that have carbon bonded to three or more non-hydrogen atoms. Those chemicals have to contain "C(" within their SMILES string.
However when I try this:
`newdf2=df[df['SMILES'].str.contains('C(')].reset_index(drop=True)`
It comes up an error: **missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 1**

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets like this:

`newdf2=df[df['SMILES'].str.contains('C\(')].reset_index(drop=True)`